# Is it possible to set the message to be displayed in the Flutter app when FCM is received in the background?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

Send the following data to the Flutter app using FCM.

```
 'data': {
   'en': 'Hello',
   'zh': '你好',
   'jp': 'こんにちは'
 }
```

Therefore, I would like to implement a function that sets the message to be displayed depending on the language code set on the terminal.
If there is something like the `show()` method of `flutter_local_notifications` in the `firebase_messaging` package, I think it would be possible to configure it, but I couldn't find it.

Is there a method in the `firebase_messaging` package that allows notification messages to be set on the Flutter app side, like the `show()` method of `flutter_local_notifications`?

Comment: If you send a `notification` message rather than a `data` message, it will automatically be displayed by the receiving system rather than your application code. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Comment: My question is not answered, so I have a question: Does this mean that FCM localization cannot be done on the app side?